# Difficulties in adding the output layer in python

Tags: machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am getting this error when I try to run my code:

```
  File "C:\Users\olaku\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'units'".
```

My code:

```
# Importing the relevant libraries.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


#importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv ('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', drop=None, sparse=True)
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X = X[:, 1:]

# Splitting the dataset into training and testing set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 123)

#Feature Scalling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Part 2: Make the Artifical Neural Network (ANN)

#Import the Keras library and packages
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


#Initialising the ANN

classifier = Sequential ()

classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))

#Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(units = 6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

#Adding the output layer

classifier.add(Dense(output = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error trace; as is, it's impossible to know where exactly in your code the error happens. When done, be sure to remove all code that comes **after** the error (it's never executed, hence irrelevant here). In the future, be also sure you have included the relevant tags (here `keras` and `scikit-learn`).

Answer (score 0):

try this changes:

```
classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 11))

#Adding the second hidden layer
classifier.add(Dense(6, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))

#Adding the output layer

classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

let me know!